# Pandas str.replace of pipe character not working?

Tags: python, pandas, special-characters

I am facing an issue in using pandas str.replace on Series. I am using pandas in Jupyter notebook (although the result is the same with regular python script).

```
import pandas as pd
s = ["abc | def"]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=s)

print(s[0].replace(" | ", "@"))
print(df[0].str.replace("| ", "@"))
print(df[0].map(lambda v: v.replace("| ", "@")))
```

Here is the result

```
ipython Untitled1.py 

abc@def
0    @a@b@c@ @|@ @d@e@f@
Name: 0, dtype: object
0    abc @def
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Also please draw direct attention to what you think is going wrong-- everything seemed to be behaving as it should, which makes it hard to point out where the confusion is.  (I suspect it's that you weren't expecting it to be parsed as regex, but it'd be good to be sure.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works if you escape the pipe.

```
>>> df[0].str.replace(" \| ", "@")
0    abc@def
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

The [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) function is equivalent to `re.sub`:

```
import re

>>> re.sub(' | ', '@', "abc | def")
'abc@|@def'

>>> "abc | def".replace(' | ', '@')
'abc@def'
```

> **`Series.str.replace(pat, repl, n=-1, case=True, flags=0)`**: Replace occurrences of pattern/regex in the Series/Index with some other string. Equivalent to `str.replace()` or `re.sub()`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, the two `replace` methods behave differently.

Comment: [`pandas.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) applies regex as per documentation

Comment: I was confused by the documentation since it is stating "Character sequence or regular expression". Thank you for the clear explanation.

Comment: @FlavienLambert: **the `pat` argument can be either a string pattern or a (compiled) regex**. Conceptually, a string pattern is equivalent to a regex without any special characters.

Comment: @FlavienLambert: "the two `replace` methods" are very different things, `str.replace()` is base Python. Whereas `pandas.Series.str.replace()` is pandas package. Different codebases in different packages.